# Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm: Max flow

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have worked on the [Ford-Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) and have following code.

The code works fine, but I fill I could do more code optimization, I have worked on it for few days.

- **Question:** Is there any remarks or comments for code improvement?

```
/**
 * src = source
 * dst = destination
 */
public class MaxFlowAlgo {

    private int vertexTotal;
    private int edgeSrcDstDirectionTotal;
    private List<Edge> edgeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Vertex> vertexList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Vertex> minCutVertexList = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void dataParsing(String folderName, String fileName) throws IOException {
        int lineCounter = 0;
        int mCounter = 0;
        String filePath = folderName + fileName;
        File fileObj = new File(filePath);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(fileObj);

        vertexTotal = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            if (lineCounter < vertexTotal) {
                vertexList.add(new Vertex(input.nextLine().trim()));
            }
            if (lineCounter == vertexTotal) {
                edgeSrcDstDirectionTotal = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                mCounter = 0;
            }
            if ((edgeSrcDstDirectionTotal + vertexTotal) >= lineCounter && lineCounter > vertexTotal) {
                Vertex srcVertex = vertexList.get(input.nextInt());
                Vertex dstVertex = vertexList.get(input.nextInt());
                int capacity = input.nextInt();
                if (capacity == -1)
                    capacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                Edge edge = new Edge(srcVertex, dstVertex, capacity, null);
                srcVertex.edges.add(edge);
                dstVertex.edges.add(edge);
                srcVertex.edges.add(edge.edgeBack);
                dstVertex.edges.add(edge.edgeBack);
                edgeList.add(edge);
                edgeList.add(edge.edgeBack);
                mCounter++;
            }

            lineCounter++;
        }
    }

    private List<Edge> bfs(Vertex srcVertex, Vertex sinkVertex) {
        boolean hasPathTo = false;
        Queue<Vertex> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(srcVertex);
        minCutVertexList.clear();
        minCutVertexList.add(srcVertex);

        while (queue.size() > 0) {
            Vertex currVertex = queue.poll();
            for (Edge edge : currVertex.edges) {
                Vertex dstVertex = edge.dstVertex;
                if (minCutVertexList.contains(dstVertex) || edge.capacityRemain() == 0)
                    continue;
                dstVertex.edgeTo = edge;
                minCutVertexList.add(dstVertex);
                if (dstVertex.equals(sinkVertex)) {
                    hasPathTo = true;
                    break;
                }
                queue.add(dstVertex);
            }
        }

        List<Edge> edgePathList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (hasPathTo) {
            Vertex vertex = sinkVertex;
            while (!vertex.equals(srcVertex)) {
                edgePathList.add(vertex.edgeTo);
                vertex = vertex.edgeTo.srcVertex;
            }
        }
        return edgePathList.size() > 0 ? edgePathList : null;
    }

    protected List<String> fordFulkerson() {
        int maxFlow = 0;
        Vertex srcVertex = vertexList.get(0);
        Vertex sinkVertex = vertexList.get(vertexTotal - 1);
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Edge> augmentPath;
        while ((augmentPath = bfs(srcVertex, sinkVertex)) != null) {
            int maxCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Edge e : augmentPath)
                maxCapacity = Math.min(e.capacityRemain(), maxCapacity);
            for (Edge e : augmentPath)
                e.flowInc(maxCapacity);
            //maxFlow results
            maxFlow += maxCapacity;
        }

        //minimum cut results
        for (Edge e : edgeList) {
            if (minCutVertexList.contains(e.srcVertex) == true && minCutVertexList.contains(e.dstVertex) == false) {
                resultList.add(vertexList.indexOf(e.srcVertex) + " " + vertexList.indexOf(e.dstVertex) + " " + e.capacity);
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    private class Edge {
        public Vertex srcVertex;
        public Vertex dstVertex;
        public Integer capacity = 0;
        public Integer flow = 0;
        public Edge edgeBack;

        public Edge(Vertex srcVertex, Vertex dstVertex, Integer capacity, Edge srcEdge) {
            this.srcVertex = srcVertex;
            this.dstVertex = dstVertex;
            this.capacity = capacity;
            if (srcEdge == null)
                this.edgeBack = new Edge(dstVertex, srcVertex, capacity, this);
            else
                this.edgeBack = srcEdge;
        }

        public void flowInc(int flow) {
            this.flow += flow;
            this.edgeBack.flow -= flow;
        }

        public int capacityRemain() {
            return capacity - flow;
        }

    }

    private class Vertex {
        public String vertexStationName;
        public List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
        public Edge edgeTo;

        public Vertex(String vertexStationName) {
            this.vertexStationName = vertexStationName;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Input Parsing.

You declare a `Scanner` to process your input, but then you don't use it very effectively. Your code:

> ```
>     input = new Scanner(fileObj);
>     vertexTotal = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
>     while (input.hasNext()) {
>         if (lineCounter < vertexTotal) {
>             vertexList.add(new Vertex(input.nextLine().trim()));
>         }
>         if (lineCounter == vertexTotal) {
>             edgeSrcDstDirectionTotal = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
>             mCounter = 0;
>         }
>         if ((edgeSrcDstDirectionTotal + vertexTotal) >= lineCounter && lineCounter > vertexTotal) {
>             Vertex srcVertex = vertexList.get(input.nextInt());
>             Vertex dstVertex = vertexList.get(input.nextInt());
>             int capacity = input.nextInt();
>             if (capacity == -1)
>                 capacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
>             Edge edge = new Edge(srcVertex, dstVertex, capacity, null);
>             srcVertex.edges.add(edge);
>             dstVertex.edges.add(edge);
>             srcVertex.edges.add(edge.edgeBack);
>             dstVertex.edges.add(edge.edgeBack);
>             edgeList.add(edge);
>             edgeList.add(edge.edgeBack);
>             mCounter++;
>         }
>
>         lineCounter++;
>     }
> ```

would be better as:

```
    input = new Scanner(fileObj);
    vertexTotal = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexTotal; i++) {
        vertexList.add(new Vertex(scanner.nextLine().trim());
    }
    edgeSrcDstDirectionTotal = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < edgeSrcDstDirectionTotal; i++) {
        Vertex srcVertex = vertexList.get(input.nextInt());
        Vertex dstVertex = vertexList.get(input.nextInt());
        int capacity = input.nextInt();
        if (capacity == -1)
            capacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Edge edge = new Edge(srcVertex, dstVertex, capacity, null);
        srcVertex.edges.add(edge);
        dstVertex.edges.add(edge);
        srcVertex.edges.add(edge.edgeBack);
        dstVertex.edges.add(edge.edgeBack);
        edgeList.add(edge);
        edgeList.add(edge.edgeBack);
    }
```

### General

In general, I am impressed with your code. It is neat, variable names are good, the logic is well structured, and I can mostly follow it without having to run it. This is a good thing. Some smallish items have impressed me too:

- you are using interfaces for variables, and not their concrete implementations. Code like `Queue<Vertex> queue = new LinkedList<>();` is good. It is common to see people making the queue a `LinkedList`, which is an anti-pattern you have avoided.
- your variables have great names,a nd are self-documenting.
- your generics all appear to be "right".

On the other hand, you have a number of items that are small, but wrong too:

- `size()` is an anti-pattern in a loop condition. Your code `while (queue.size() > 0) {` should instead be: `while (!queue.isEmpty()) {`
- Even 1-liner if-blocks should have braces - it prevents maintenance bugs later. This code:

  > ```
  >         if (minCutVertexList.contains(dstVertex) || edge.capacityRemain() == 0)
  >             continue;
  > ```

  should be:

  ```
          if (minCutVertexList.contains(dstVertex) || edge.capacityRemain() == 0) {
              continue;
          }
  ```

  While we are on it, you may improve performance if you put the capacity-check first.
- The complete while-loop in the bfs method should be a function, and it should return true. The `break` condition should instead be `return true`. Then your code becomes:

  ```
  if(!hasPathTo(sinkVertex)) {
      return null;
  }
  List<Edge> edgePathList = new ArrayList<>();
  Vertex vertex = sinkVertex;
  while (!vertex.equals(srcVertex)) {
      edgePathList.add(vertex.edgeTo);
      vertex = vertex.edgeTo.srcVertex;
  }
  return edgePathList;
  ```
- Your `Edge` and `Vertex` classes should both be static - it will save having a pointer back to the outer class that you never use.

Comment: Great and useful input thump up. I GO a head fixing it, and let you

Comment: Feedback, I followed your advice and input. It is genius good, every thing is working top now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of points which the existing answer missed, one of which I consider quite important.

#### Datatypes

```
    private List<Edge> edgeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Vertex> vertexList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Vertex> minCutVertexList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Why are these lists?

`edgeList` is appended to in the parsing stage and iterated over in the output stage, so it could be any `Collection`. `List` is as reasonable as any; I personally would use `Set`, but I can see an argument that `List` is more efficient.

`vertexList` is appended to in the parsing stage and looked up by index when parsing the edges, so it has to be a `List`. **But** the output stage calls `vertexList.indexOf` in a loop, and there it would be more efficient to pre-compute a `Map<Vertex, Integer>` (or to store the index as a field of the `Vertex`).

`minCutVertexList` is cleared, added to, and tested for `contains`. It should be a `Set`, because `List.contains` is always going to be a `O(n)` operation.

#### Unused variables

I don't see any reads of `mCounter` or `maxFlow` except in their self-updates (`++` and `+=` respectively). Maybe they were for debugging or you changed your mind about the signatures of the methods, but they can be deleted now.

#### Style

Style is always disputable, so these are opinions, but I hope that they're at least majority opinions.

- `edgeList` etc. are a form of Hungarian notation. The IDE will tell us that they're lists (or set, in the case of the min cut vertices, after applying the suggestion above). I would prefer `edges`, `vertices`, and either `minCutVertices` or just `minCut`.
- Comparisons to Boolean literals are ugly. `if (minCutVertexList.contains(e.srcVertex) == true && minCutVertexList.contains(e.dstVertex) == false)` could just be `if (minCutVertexList.contains(e.srcVertex) && !minCutVertexList.contains(e.dstVertex))`